# Difficulty understanding how to pull information from model with parse and show in view

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform

So I am helping to extend some functionality from an iOS app into a Parse/backbone style app. I am able to get information from the Parse database, but am having a difficult time understand how to render that with a view.

Here is the code I have so far

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>My Parse App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main">
      <h1 id="actual_question"></h1>
    <script type="text/template" id="question">

    </script>




  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    Parse.initialize("hidden-for-security", "hidden-for-security");

    var Question = Parse.Object.extend("Question");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Question);

    query.get("fhLIwu6zst", {
        success: function (Question) {
            var questionText = Question.get('questionText');
            alert(questionText);

        },
        error: function (object, error) {
            alert('terrible failure');
        }
    });


    var questionView = Parse.View.extend({

        el: '#actual_question',

        initialize: function() {

            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {

           this.$el.html("something");
        }
    });

    var questionView = new questionView({});

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

For the query the alert shows that I have successfully pulled that information from the database. Where I have "something" in the questionView i'd like to display that same query information but am having trouble with those. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Create your view with model.

```
var questionView = new questionView({
    model: query 
});
```

In your render method you should use some templating or whatever you want.

Read [here](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render) about it.

```
render: function() {
    var compiled = _.template("Id: <%= Id %>");
    this.$el.html(compiled(this.model.toJSON()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you this helps and I've read that documentation,but I"m still struggling to understand what I would put where I have "something" and how I can pass in that specific ID of "fhLIwu6zst"?

Comment: Excuse my newbynish, but still having trouble with this. In parse the unique id would be 'objectId', I still dont' understand how I am passing in this object id. With the code provided it just says Id is undefined.

Comment: 'this.model.toJSON()' create object with all model attributes as properties. In template just place all needed properties. (replace Id to objectId)